# listing YAML Nodes

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am quite new to YAML and Python both. I am trying to list down all keys and values in my YAML file. But couldn't figure out the way to do it. Appriciate help.

### YAML File

```
---
    Task_T0:
      -
       args:
            task_path: "..."
       executor:
            type: "T0"

    Task_T1:
      -
       args:
           task_path: "~/task_file"
       executor:
           type: "T1"
       data:
         params:
            p1: 0
```

I wants to list down all Nodes (Task_T...).
Here is what tried as i couldn't find any API to do so :

```
 parsed_task = yaml.safe_load(rendered_task)
 for task_obj in enumerate(parsed_task):
     path = task_obj[0]["args"]["task_path"]
     print("task path::" + path)
```

I am getting this error :

```
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If i modify my code to :

```
parsed_task = yaml.safe_load(rendered_task)
for task_obj in enumerate(parsed_task):
     path = task_obj["args"]["task_path"]
     print("task path::" + path)
```

Then i am getting this error :

```
tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Can you at least post some code, to show us your attempts ? If you really cannot wrap your mind around pyyaml see: [PyYAML doc](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

Comment: Added my tried code. Please don't blame my bad python coding.

Comment: It's ok, you are here to learn. Nobody is here to blame people. Can you please, post all code ? `rendered_task` doesn't exist. Try to make it easier for use to help by posting a runnable example.

Comment: The python code is invalid, you have to indent the line(s) following the `for ....:`. If you want all of the keys and values, you have to make a function that calls itself recursively on the values if they are sequences or mappings, as these can contain further key-value pairs.

Comment: Single `-` you use is interpreted by YAML as a *sequence element*. Either remove it (so your code become worked), or use `task_obj[0]["args"]["task_path"]` for access corresponded fields.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. Can you let me know how can i access the name of the document. I.e. Root element of task_obj in this case value "Task_T0" & "Task_T1".

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working using below code :

```
parsed_task = yaml.safe_load(task_file)
for task_obj in enumerate(parsed_task):
    name = task_obj[1]
    print("task name:" + name)
```

Above code prints names of tasks.
If you want to have more details of each task then

```
parsed_task = yaml.safe_load(rendered_task)
for scenario_obj in enumerate(parsed_task):
    name = scenario_obj[1]
    print("scenario name:" + name)
    print(parsed_task[name][0]["args"]["task_path"])
```

Above code would print task path for each node.

Comment: Actually, `enumerate(parsed_task)` returns list of *tuples* `(index, value)`. That why you need additional indexing `[1]`. If you need only the values, use `values(parsed_task)` instead.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely correct. thanks for tip to get values.